# Can't sign in to MongoDB Atlas

Tags: mongodb-atlas

I am trying to sign in to MongoDB Atlas Cloud but once I get to auth.mongodb.com I receive an empty response "ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE".

I mean, I am just trying to loggin. What could possible be wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after digging a little more I found out that Bitdifender Firewall was blocking the auth.mongodb.com route therefore I couldn't get a response from the server.